# Why does the height of my div element not change (HTML only)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

I'm trying to embed [this stock market chart] into my blog. I selected `autosize: true`, to adjust the width responsively to the site width but want to set a fixed height (eg, 500px).

Even though, I read a lot on stackoverflow and tested different things, I can't get it to work. I tried adding `style` fields in the `div` element and also tried adding a parent `div`.
Here's the example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="min-height: 500px; height: 500px; width: 500px;">
  <div id="tradingview_b9e4a"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/SWB-LYYA/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">LYYA Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "SWB:LYYA",
  "timezone": "exchange",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "2",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "hide_top_toolbar": true,
  "hide_legend": true,
  "withdateranges": true,
  "range": "5d",
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "save_image": false,
  "container_id": "tradingview_b9e4a"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
</body>
</html>
```

I expected/wanted the plot to be square (500x500px), but the resulting chart is always really flat and the height doesn't change - no matter what I tried:

[image]

I want to do this just in HTML, without extra CSS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the height on `.tradingview_b9e4` element. the first child of `.tradingview-widget-container`;

```
<div id="tradingview_b9e4a" style="height: 100%;"
```

Comment: Because it otherwise doesn't use the full height (for whatever reason), even if I set `height` and `min-height` to 500px?

Comment: initially, when the chart was small in height, that height was the height of content of `.tradingview_b9e4` . but you were setting the height of the `.tradingview-widget-container` but that does not apply for its child `.tradingview_b9e4`. but when you set height 100% `.tradingview_b9e4` it will take its parent height which is `500px`. @CGFoX

Comment: Ah ok, so style isn't inherited to children automatically? I'm new to web development as you can see.

Comment: Yes ! some of the CSS properties are inherited but not every CSS property is inherited by default by children. most of the font-related and some few other properties are inherited e.g `font-family`, `font-weight`, `line-height`, `visibility`.